# Image cover parent with all image sizes

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app where I display three images in a three column row. Images that are added into these columns can be of any size and thats whats currently causing me issues. With the CSS I have in place all images that are "tall and thin" or "square" are fine however any images that are "short and wide" are causing me some trouble. I would like the images to fill the full square of the column however with the "short and wide" images they are not filling the height correctly. Heres my example:

[image]

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ion-col {
    position: relative;
}

ion-col .card-img-list-item {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

ion-col .card-img-list-item img {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

<ion-row class="card-img-list row">
  <ion-col class="col">
      <div class="card-img-list-item">
            <img _ngcontent-c0="" src="http://www.slp-photography.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Lake-District-Landscape-Photography-Swirral-Edge-Sunset-Portrait.jpg">
      </div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="col">
      <div class="card-img-list-item">
            <img _ngcontent-c0="" src="http://www.thinkdunes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Beach-Cove-1600x500.png">
      </div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="col">
      <div class="card-img-list-item">
            <img _ngcontent-c0="" src="https://images.on-this.website/4770_16177414785089a40b8a364.jpg">
      </div>
  </ion-col>

</ion-row>
```

See example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kAaFNjewMvT43LPddkL8?p=preview

As you can see the middle image is not filling the height of the parent div.

I dont really want to change the structure of the HTML if possible and because of the library I am using to display the images I cant set the image as a background-image in CSS.

I also dont want to change how the other two images are displayed so I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try this CSS for the image:  height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        width:100%;

Comment: Thats not quite what im after as it stretches/squashes the image rather than setting it to the center of the parent

Comment: So you want the image yo fill width and height and be centered in the middle of the parent div?

Comment: Okay so I want the image to either fill the height (with the width being larger than the parent width) and have the image center horizontally OR have the image fill the width (with the height being larger than the parent height) and have the image center vertically. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Your best bet is to use a background image and `background-size: cover`

Comment: Please check duplicate link, and check the support. It will give result like http://plnkr.co/edit/NFwt3Rl89NsQmdlQsWsF?p=preview